# Dwm conflicting types when compiling C file

Tags: c, compiler-errors, x-dwm

I added a patch to dwm, I eventually manually patched it, but after I tried compiling I get this error

```
drw.c:64:1: error: conflicting types for 'drw_create'; have 'Drw *(Display *, int,  Window,  unsigned int,  unsigned int,  Visual *, unsigned int,  Colormap)' {aka 'Drw *(Display *, int,  long unsigned int,  unsigned int,  unsigned int,  Visual *, unsigned int,  long unsigned int)'}
```

I'm using arch linux if that matters

I think this is the part that matters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xft/Xft.h>

#include "drw.h"
#include "util.h"

#define UTF_INVALID 0xFFFD
#define UTF_SIZ     4

static const unsigned char utfbyte[UTF_SIZ + 1] = {0x80,    0, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0};
static const unsigned char utfmask[UTF_SIZ + 1] = {0xC0, 0x80, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF8};
static const long utfmin[UTF_SIZ + 1] = {       0,    0,  0x80,  0x800,  0x10000};
static const long utfmax[UTF_SIZ + 1] = {0x10FFFF, 0x7F, 0x7FF, 0xFFFF, 0x10FFFF};

static long
utf8decodebyte(const char c, size_t *i)
{
    for (*i = 0; *i < (UTF_SIZ + 1); ++(*i))
        if (((unsigned char)c & utfmask[*i]) == utfbyte[*i])
            return (unsigned char)c & ~utfmask[*i];
    return 0;
}

static size_t
utf8validate(long *u, size_t i)
{
    if (!BETWEEN(*u, utfmin[i], utfmax[i]) || BETWEEN(*u, 0xD800, 0xDFFF))
        *u = UTF_INVALID;
    for (i = 1; *u > utfmax[i]; ++i)
        ;
    return i;
}

static size_t
utf8decode(const char *c, long *u, size_t clen)
{
    size_t i, j, len, type;
    long udecoded;

    *u = UTF_INVALID;
    if (!clen)
        return 0;
    udecoded = utf8decodebyte(c[0], &len);
    if (!BETWEEN(len, 1, UTF_SIZ))
        return 1;
    for (i = 1, j = 1; i < clen && j < len; ++i, ++j) {
        udecoded = (udecoded << 6) | utf8decodebyte(c[i], &type);
        if (type)
            return j;
    }
    if (j < len)
        return 0;
    *u = udecoded;
    utf8validate(u, len);

    return len;
}

Drw *
drw_create(Display *dpy, int screen, Window root, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, Visual *visual, unsigned int depth, Colormap cmap)
{
    Drw *drw = ecalloc(1, sizeof(Drw));

    drw->dpy = dpy;
    drw->screen = screen;
    drw->root = root;
    drw->w = w;
    drw->h = h;
    drw->drawable = XCreatePixmap(dpy, root, w, h, DefaultDepth(dpy, screen));
    drw->gc = XCreateGC(dpy, root, 0, NULL);
    XSetLineAttributes(dpy, drw->gc, 1, LineSolid, CapButt, JoinMiter);

    return drw;
}
```

I googled this type of error and i do understand the concept of how it should be solved but i unfortunately don't know C and that file is huge, its hard for me understand with 0 C knowledge

Comment: Where did you download the patch from? Why did you download the patch? What is the actual problem you have? What problem is the patch supposed to solve?

Comment: The patch is from the official suckless.org website.

Comment: It's called systray (https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/systray/)

Comment: It's not possible to answer the question without knowing _exactly_ what files you downloaded and how _exactly_ you applied the patch. For what it's worth, the code in the question is _not_ the latest version of DWM: https://git.suckless.org/dwm/file/drw.c.html#l64